# Getting Group to Work Properly in VBA Code

Tags: vba, function

I am trying to hide some columns by using a Group function in my VBA code. The group is showing on my outputted Excel file, but it is not collapsing the columns like I am expecting it to. Any ideas on what I am missing to get these columns to collapse properly?

```
xlBook.ActiveSheet.Columns("A").AutoFit
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
'xlBook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

With xlBook.ActiveSheet.Columns("B:O")
 .Group
End With

xlBook.ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels columnLevels:=1
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = True


xlSheet.Columns.AutoFit
```

Comment: *"but it is not collapsing the columns like I am expecting it to"* - Can you post a screenshot of what it's doing now, and another of what your expected behavior is?

Comment: Seems that you're trying to group columns that are part of a pivot table. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes @RicardoDiaz that is correct, I am trying to group columns part of a pivot table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping whole columns when there is a pivot table behind is not allowed.

The path would be to group the elements inside the pivot table.

As I see you're doing this from another application, please try to use the macro recorder to select the pivot table column labels that you want to group, and then click on the "data" / "group" button in the ribbon.

Copy the generated code and try to adapt it.

Here is a good reference you can follow:
http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=153:excel-pivot-tables-grouping-group-items-group-data-and-group-date-values-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475

Let me know if this helps.